# Does my Cloud Function "own" its IP address while it is running?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Can I assume that while my cloud function is running, no other cloud function (that is also currently running) also has the same IP address? In other words, do I "own" the IP address of the cloud function during the time in which it is running?

My guess is no, since it would just cost Google more money to do that without much benefit for 95% of users, but I couldn't find any info on this anywhere, hence this question.

If my intuition is correct, then perhaps the only way to be sure that my function has a unique IP is to assign it a static IP? As of writing, static IPs for Cloud Functions are [apparently in beta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56907114/10898116).

Answer (score 0):

Currently, as the product stands, you can not assume that if you make an outgoing request from Cloud Functions that it will appear to come from an IP address, with no other outgoing traffic from any other functions appearing to come from it.  As you've seen in the other question, there are blocks of addresses that Google owns, and the traffic could appear to come from anywhere within those blocks, depending on the region of deployment and other factors.  You can expect that there are going to be far more Cloud Functions deployed for all projects for all customers running concurrently than there are specific IPs within those blocks.  So you should not make any assumptions about the IP of origination.  It could change at any time, and any function's or project's traffic may appear to come from it.

If this situation changes due to additional features offered by Cloud Functions, you might get a different set of guarantees, but it's not clear what those are without being in this beta program.

Answer (score 0):

Doug is right. There is any guaranty of the IP address. And I don't hear about any alpha/beta program with static public IP.

However, there is an beta program called [vpc connector](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-serverless-vpc-access), in networks section in the console, which allows you to define a small range of IP (cidr /28)  to be used by function to enter in the VPC of your project. You can then set up all the route and the firewall rules that you want with this range in your VPC.

Finally, about the early Access mentioned in the link, and which shouldn't be public, it's not exactly that. Stay tuned.