# IP address for firebase function and cloud storage triggers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, amazon-rds

I am using firebase functions and Cloud Storage triggers(.onCreate).

I have to connect AWS RDS(mysql) and vpc is enable in aws rds.

I have to whitelist IP to connect aws-rds so please let me know how we will get the firebase function and cloud storage trigger IP.

Comment: There is no permanent IP address for servers running Cloud Functions.

Comment: @DougStevenson, Thanks for reply!

Can we connect aws-rds by accessKeyId and secretAccessKey?
I have created one user(IAM role) and provided permission to rds.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to get an ip address(es) in order to whitelist a cloud function instance by ip, check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811882/possible-to-get-static-ip-address-for-google-cloud-functions).

The only workaround I could think of is using [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions)

Comment: Now, GCP has an alternative that could be useful, you can find the details in this link. For this to work, you will need to deploy a GCP Cloud Function, which is not exactly the same as a Cloud Function for Firebase; check the following quickstart for more details:

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart

It's worth a try.