# Get IP address Of my Firebase Cloud Fucntion

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I need to access some external API from my Firebase cloud function.
However, they need me to add my server IP to their IP Whitelist. Do I have the possibility to get the external IP address of a firebase cloud function?

P.S: an IP identification website give me 216.239.36.54 as the address. Is It right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloud Functions are automatically provisioned and unprovisioned as requests are made to them, so they are not on a fixed IP address. If you wait 15 minutes, you might get a different IP address, and if you get many users they will be served from multiple different IP addresses.

The external API will need to allow access from the entire range of IP addresses that Cloud Functions may use. Alternatively, the documentation suggests that you can [associate function egress traffic with a static IP address](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip). Note that this last option seems non-trivial to me from a quick scan of the documentation.

Also see:

- [Possible to get static IP address for Google Cloud Functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811882/possible-to-get-static-ip-address-for-google-cloud-functions)