# How to obtain the public ip address from my google cloud platform project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, ip-address

I am trying to get the public ip address from my GCP project so i can access AWS (protected by ip). I tried using Cloud Shell to get the public ip address of my GCP project or my Google Cloud Functions, but i am not sure what ip is my public ip, or what command should i use.
Can someone show me where or how to get the address of my project?
or what public ip address Google Functions use?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

Comment: Is your question about the public IP address of Cloud Shell or another service? Edit your question with more details.

Comment: Just edited my question, thanks

Comment: 1) Google Cloud Projects (the resource) does not have a public IP address. Some services such as Google Compute Engine and load balancers do/can have public IP addresses assigned. 2) Cloud Functions do not have static public IP addresses. You can use Serverless VPC Access with Cloud Functions to route functions traffic through your VPC. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip

Comment: @JohnHanley so the region of my cloud function will define the ip address that it use?

Comment: Associating function egress with a static IP address
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip

Comment: Yes, the region will affect the range of IP addresses that Cloud Functions use. However, your function does not have its own public IP address. There is a Google frontend that proxies requests. External applications see the frontend's IP address which is a pool of addresses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Projects (the resource) does not have a [public IP address](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip). Some services such as Google Compute Engine and load balancers do/can have public IP addresses assigned. 2) Cloud Functions do not have static public IP addresses. You can use Serverless VPC Access with Cloud Functions to route functions traffic through your VPC.

The region will affect the range of IP addresses that Cloud Functions use. However, your function does not have its own public IP address. There is a Google frontend that proxies requests. External applications see the frontend's IP address which is a pool of addresses.

[@John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley)

Comment: Compute engine instances have static IP's assigned on boot; on reboot they can change.

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address

List static external IP addresses
To list static external IP addresses that you have reserved for your project, use the console, run compute addresses list or make a GET request to the API.

In gcloud
Use the compute addresses list command

```
gcloud compute addresses list
```

Comment: This answer does not apply to Cloud Functions, which is what the OP asked about. It is correct for some services.

Comment: thanks for the aclaration John

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/networking/network-settings#associate-static-ip

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38811882/possible-to-get-static-ip-address-for-google-cloud-functions

hope this helps!